# Draft messages in Mountain Lion Mail do not include server draft messages

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I had a clean install Mountain Lion on my Macbook Pro, early 2011.

Following suggestions in the forums, I carried my "Mail" folders (folders, preferences, etc) from my cloned backup of Snow Leopard.

Mountain Lion Mail automatically created the necessary accounts in the new way it is set up.

However, the local Drafts folders do not include my drafted messages in individual IMAP e-mail accounts (yahoo, gmail, uni, etc).

I can see these draf messages under the folders of these individual e-mail accounts. But they are not like drafts. I cannot edit them. I have same controls as in the messages that are sent to me.

on the other hand, if I open a new message, type somethings and close without sending, that message goes into the Drafts folder.

How can I go around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have an iMac (Mountain Lion.)  I couldn't edit any of my drafts.  I finally found that all I had to do was click FORWARD and then when the email comes on the screen I can edit.  (Too bad extra steps have to be taken, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If you move the drafts from the email's draft folder into Mail's draft folder Mail then treats them as drafts so you can then edit them as drafts. Though this is could be a very tedious process and I could not really find a way for Mail to do this automatically.